# where does actionlistener go?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm a little bit lost with a PrimeFaces program I'm trying to understand.

Basically I have a Car.xhtml page.
On this page I have a

```
commandbutton "id=save" "actionListener="#{CarView.save}"
```

To me it seemed pretty obvious that if I click on the button I m supposed to launch  a method called save on the CarView.java.

There is a method save, but whatever I do, it seems that it's never called.

If I change `"`{carView.save}`"` into "`{carView.save2}`"` it tells me save2 doesn't exist and if I change the method save(ActionEvent actionEvent) into save2(ActionEvent actionEvent), I have the same message.

I cannot find any other method with the name save. And this program actually saves everything.I've spent a few hours but I'm still lost. Where should I look ?

Comment: Try camel case: `actionListener="#{carView.save}`,

Comment: sorry I think I wasn't clear but this programs works, I just don't get how it works

Comment: `#{CarView.save}` and `#{carView.save}` are fundementally different. Which one is it? And how is the bean declared. Even if it works , always post a [mcve]. You have several typo's in your code above that a real mcve helps. (and a`save(ActionEvent actionEvent)` _**is**_ called, no other option...

Comment: Maybe you don't build after u make changes on your bean!! this link can help understand actionListner https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener